# Highstock xAxis scaling

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm having the same problem explained in
[Format Highcharts xAxis for stock data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398062/format-highcharts-xaxis-for-stock-data) problem when using the Highstock library when the candlestick type is used.

using the same solution described there does not solve the problem with the Highstock library (although both libraries are built around the same principle from the same developer).

Comment: I see this question getting up-votes, I must be stupid.. I'm not getting the question. Do you think you can add an example that explains the problem a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "max" property on xAxis, since this is a timeline series it needs to be of a datetime type.

Here is a jsfiddle example of a random stock in the US market, starting at 9:30 , xAxis max needs to be set to 9:30 + 6.5 hours

http://jsfiddle.net/eUtDD/

```
max: first time stamp in the series + length
```

so

```
max: 1320658200000 + (3600000 * 6.5)
```